# Spring MVC PUT versus PATCH

Tags: spring, rest, patch, put

For my usecase i should be using PATCH to do a partial update. But i am just wondering what springMVC does different with RequestMEthod.PUT versus RequestMethod.PATCH?

FYI @RequestBody object is getting populated in same way with either PUT or PATCH.

Comment: Spring MVC doesn't do anything. "All" it does is receiving the request and let you handle it from a controller method. It's up to you to do whatever you want.

Comment: Adding a link to a good post that explains how to use patch, as I have the feeling it will be miss used in this case: http://williamdurand.fr/2014/02/14/please-do-not-patch-like-an-idiot/

Comment: I've put together a [post](https://cassiomolin.com/using-http-patch-in-spring/) that describes an approach for using `PATCH` in Spring. And a working example is available on [GitHub](https://github.com/cassiomolin/http-patch-spring).

Answer (score 1):

PUT and PATCH are `HTTP` methods.

Spring's `RequestMethod` only wraps them. So the question should be when to use `HTTP PUT` and `HTTP PATCH`.

According to [this](http://restful-api-design.readthedocs.org/en/latest/methods.html):

> The HTTP RFC specifies that PUT must take a full new resource
>   representation as the request entity.

While

> PATCH is like PUT in that it updates a resource, but unlike PUT, it
>   applies a delta rather than replacing the entire resource.
>
> For simple resource representations, the difference is often not important.

So since it is only semantic (you can do whatever you want in the controller once you get the request), and i suppose your rest-api does not include complex updates of, say, a part of a list or specific fields in nested Objects - i believe `PUT` would be the better choice.